# How can I reprint a string starting from the first character till the last?

Tags: java

> Given a non-empty string str like "Code" print a string like "CCoCodCode". Where at each index in the string you have to reprint the string up to that index.

I know there is DEFINITELY something wrong with this code that I wrote because the answer should be CCoCodCode, but instead it's giving me the alphabet! I don't know how I should change it.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      String str = scan.next();
        int x = str.length();
        for(char i = str.charAt(0); i <= str.charAt(x-1); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `char` datatype can be treated as a number; you can increment it and manipulate it as a number.

What you really want is successive substrings of `str` to be printed.  Loop over an `int` that will represent the ending position of the substring to be printed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.print(str.substring(0, i + 1));
}
```

The end index argument to [`substring` is exclusive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), which is why I added `1`.

Comment: Thank u so much! Do you know how i can practice more on these stuff? I keep complicating the question when in fact it's very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that `str` is `"Code"`. We can perform some mental substitutions to see what happens to your loop.

- `str` is `"Code"`
- `x` is `4`
- `str.charAt(0)` is `'C'`
- `str.charAt(x-1)` is `'e'`

Making these substitutions, your loop is:

```
for(char i = 'C'; i <= 'e'; i++)
{
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

Does this help you see the problem? I would think you'd have a loop from `0` to `3`, not from `'C'` to `'e'`...

Answer (score 0):

It is outputting the alphabet because you are printing the counter instead of the characters in the string!

As it is, the first iteration of the for loop will set i to the first character, print that, then the operation `i++` will increment `i` by one. Wait, so if the first character is "C", so `i = 'C'`, what is `i++`?

Well it turns out characters can be represented by numbers. For example, 'C' has a value of 67. So incrementing it makes it 68, which represents 'D'. So if you run the loop on "Code", it will increment your counter 4 times, giving "CDEF". If you run on "Codecodecode", that will make the loop run 12 times, giving "CDEFGHIJKLMN".

What you really want is to loop through the string by its index instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.next();
    int length = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.print(str.substring(0, i + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops! I meant counter!

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to get it done, suppose we have the input from user stored in a string named "c"... then...

```
        String c = "Code";
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(c.substring(0, i));
        }
        System.out.print(c);
```

And this will print the sequence you are looking for.